# Can't extend desktop to 4th monitor

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I had all 4 displays connected and working fine this morning, then I tried to move one of the monitors to the other side of the desk and everything is now completely screwed up.

Here's what the state is right now.  I have the desktop duplicated on displays 1 (laptop screen) and 4 (monitor I'm trying to move), and extended to 2 and 3 (monitors already connected).

[image]

If I select "Extend desktop on 1 and 4" and try to apply, it says it can't save the configuration:

[image]

If I then try to make any changes to display 4 or click "detect", explorer crashes, then when it restarts the configuration is back to the original above.

I can select "Show desktop only on 1", in which case monitor 4 shuts off and I have a good configuration between 1, 2, and 3:

[image]

But If I try to then select Monitor 4 and select "Extend desktop to this display" the dropdown just instantly reverts back to "Disconnect this display"

As I said, these 4 monitors were working just fine this morning.  But for some reason when I disconnected the 4th monitor and tried to reconnect it, everything broke. I have rebooted to no avail.

**Edit**:  I also just discovered that the previews of windows when I press Alt+Tab is no longer working.  I just get icons.  I can't capture a screenshot of this.

**Edit 2**: Here's the information about my graphics card:

AMD FirePro M6100 FireGL V
Display 2 is connected via display port, display 3 via DVI, display 4 via VGA.  All are connected by a docking station, not directly to the laptop (Dell Precision M6800)